# Type mismatch when comparing two strings

Tags: excel, vba, type-mismatch

I have the following code that is comparing a combobox on a userform(GUI) to a populated cell on sheet2 of my workbook and I am getting a "type mismatch" error. This was all working until another sub shifted some data into the cells being compared on sheet 2.

My issue lies with `if Worksheets(sheet2).cells(1,i).value = LCase(GUI.superCB.Value) then`

`Worksheets(sheet2).cells(1,i).value` Now shows up in the watch as a Variant/Integer which made me think that when the data was shifted it changed the "style" of that cell.

```
Private Sub NextButton_Click() ''' adds check boxes to frame

Dim i As Integer
'Dim superColm As Integer
For i = 5 To 12
    If Worksheets(Sheet2).Cells(1, i).Value = LCase(GUI.superCB.Value) Then 'problem line is right here
        superColm = i
        Exit For
    Else
    End If
Next i

NextButton.Visible = False
superCB.Visible = False

Run.Visible = True
Frame1.Visible = True



    Dim chk As Control
    Dim idx As Integer

    Dim lastrow As Integer
    lastrow = Worksheets(Sheet2).Cells(Rows.Count, superColm).End(xlUp).Row

    For idx = 1 To lastrow - 1
        Set chk = GUI.Frame1.Controls.add("Forms.CheckBox.1", idx, True)
        'set chk = gui.Frame1.Controls.Add(
        chk.Visible = True
        chk.Left = 5
        chk.Top = (idx - 1) * (chk.Height + 2)
        chk.Caption = Cells(idx + 1, superColm) & "   " & idx
    Next
    With Me.Frame1
        .ScrollBars = fmScrollBarsVertical
            If lastrow <= 10 Then
                .ScrollHeight = .InsideHeight * 1.5
            ElseIf lastrow <= 15 Then
                .ScrollHeight = .InsideHeight * 2.25
            ElseIf lastrow <= 20 Then
                .ScrollHeight = .InsideHeight * 3
            ElseIf lastrow <= 25 Then
                .ScrollHeight = .InsideHeight * 3.9
            ElseIf lastrow <= 30 Then
                .ScrollHeight = .InsideHeight * 4.75
            ElseIf lastrow <= 35 Then
                .ScrollHeight = .InsideHeight * 5.35
            Else
                .ScrollHeight = .InsideHeight * 6.25
            End If
        .ScrollWidth = .InsideWidth * 9
    End With
End Sub
```

If I have sheet 2 as the active sheet `Cells(1,i).value` will work however, I need to have sheet 2 hidden from the user in the end. With this working it makes me think that the cell style is not the issue.

I have tried going to `Excel.Workbooks("Shawn_sch_v1.2.xlsm").worksheets(sheet2).cells(1,i).value` and everything down to the base cells() hoping it was missing a sheet reference but nothing has helped.

Comment: do you have errors in the sheet?

Comment: Not that I know of or that have been brought to my attention. Can you recommend anything that I should be looking for?

Comment: Without the variables declared, variant types can change depending on how the data is treated. It looks like comparing a range value to a form control value.

Comment: Are you recomending declaring like below?

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim superColm As Integer
    Dim sheetName As String
    sheetName = Worksheets(Sheet2).Cells(1, i).Value
    For i = 5 To 12
    If sheetName = LCase(GUI.superCB.Value) Then
    superColm = i
    Exit For
    Else
    End If
    Next i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `String` can safely be compared against any other data type in VBA... *except* `Error`.

Comparing a `Variant/Error` against anything will throw a *type mismatch* error.

This code is implicitly accessing whatever `ActiveSheet` is:

```
chk.Caption = Cells(idx + 1, superColm) & "   " & idx
```

`Cells` should be qualified with the specific `Worksheet` object you mean to work with. If the active sheet contains a value that can't be coerced into a `String` (e.g. `#VALUE!` or `#REF!`), that will throw a *type mismatch* error.

> ```
> Worksheets(Sheet2).Cells(1, i).Value = ...
> ```

Here `Sheet2` is an *identifier*. The `Worksheets` indexer wants either an integer value, or a string. If `Sheet2` is the code name of a worksheet in `ThisWorkbook`, you don't need to dereference it from `Worksheets` - just use it:

```
Sheet2.Cells(1, i).Value = ...
```

The `Worksheet` class doesn't have a *default property*, so `Debug.Print Worksheets(Sheet2)` throws error 438 *object doesn't support this property or method* - and a subsequent member call like `.Cells(1, i)`, also throws a *type mismatch* error. If you don't have a `Sheet2` string variable holding a worksheet name, I suspect that's the bug you're having right now... which means everything above is just what's waiting to bite you :)

If `Sheet2` *is* a string variable that contains a valid sheet name, you can use the `IsError` function to verify whether a `Variant` is a `Variant/Error`:

```
If Not IsError(Sheet2.Cells(1, i).Value) Then
    ' value is safe to compare against a string
Else
    ' comparing the cell value to anything will throw error 13
End If
```

Lastly, I would advise against using `Rows` as a global variable, since it's already a global-scope identifier (`[_Global].Rows`, implicitly referring to `ActiveSheet`). Now, renaming that variable with Find/Replace is going to be pretty hard to do without breaking your code: [Rubberduck](http://www.github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck)'s "rename" refactoring could probably help with doing that safely (disclaimer: I manage that OSS VBIDE add-in project).

Comment: The issue is `Worksheets` being used. I typically use `Sheets` instead. I didn't catch this difference.

Comment: @DavidS `Worksheets`/`Sheets` makes no difference. The only difference is that `Sheets` can give you a `Chart` object, which is another kind of problem - you **should** use `Worksheets` if you're looking for a `Worksheet`. The problem is that a `Worksheet` object is being passed as a parameter... to retrieve *that very same worksheet* - the collection lookup isn't even needed in the first place, assuming `Sheet2` is a `Worksheet` and not a `String`.

Comment: Mathieu thank you for taking the time to write this us. I think i was able to catch most of what you were saying. Sadly, I think my issue was that I somehow moved my `iRange=` above where the variable was being set. I also changed the .value to a .text at the same time so that may have helped also. i will keep the error checking in mind for if it comes back.  Thank you all!

Comment: @MathieuGuindon what do you recommend insted of `rows`? 
`lastrow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, superColm).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: @Gman you do realize that `iRange=` is nowhere in your original question (that `iRange` error has nothing to do with your type mismatch), and that VBA seamlessly performs implicit type conversions all the time - no integer/string comparison will ever throw a type mismatch; `Empty` happily converts to an empty string for comparisons, and no worksheet cell will ever be `Nothing`. Anyway, beware of implicit `ActiveSheet` references. `Rows.Count` is one, and yes, `lastRow` would be a much better name for something that means "the last row".

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Yes sir I know it wasn't in my original question. Like most things in my life I know just enough VBA to unknowingly back my self into a very dark corner. In my original Q I was trying the exact location indexers (correct term?) because at other times in this program I have had to do that because i have multiple workbooks open. I was truly throwing things at the wall hoping something would stick and took the above comments as "well heck, they know more than me, cant believe I missed that.

Comment: @Gman I don't want to confuse you. The whole `iRange` part of my answer is actually not helping in correcting the problem you originally had. This answer is the solution. However, I highly recommend using meaningful variable names. `iRange` was selected as it is the iterated range that cycles through your loop. For something like rows I usually do `rowCounter` or `lastRow` or `nextRow`. Just something to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

This will be fixed with doing a check on the range object data type first.

`Worksheets(Sheet2).Cells(1, i).Value` is the range object. This can change data types every time the range is modified depending on how it is modified.

`LCase(GUI.superCB.Value)` This appears to be a form control. If the range is an integer, they cannot compare.

Try something like this:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim iRange as String
'Dim superColm As Integer
`This is untested
For i = 5 To 12
iRange = Worksheets(sheet2).Cells(1, i).Text
If iRange = LCase(GUI.superCB.Value) Then 'problem line is right here
    superColm = i
    Exit For
Else
End If
Next i
```

The idea is to first be sure that the data types are the same.

You may need to use `.Text` or `.Value2` instead of `.Value` for the range. If it is possible that the range object will be `Empty` or `Nothing` , then you also need to check for those too.

Edit: Changed `.Value` to `.Text`
Edit2: This answer is incorrect.

Comment: David S I gave that a try and I am getting the same error (run time 13-Type mismatch) on the `iRange= worksheets(sheet2).cells(1,i).value`

What can we try next?     cells(1,i) is still showing type- variant/integer in the watch.

Comment: `GUI.superCB.value` is showing Type- variant/String in the watch.

Comment: What is the actual value in the cell being referenced at the error? @Gman

Comment: @ScottCraner it doesn't make it far enough to reference cells 5-12 (whom contain names).  
I tried to past a snip, but no luck.
The debug highlights `iRange = Worksheets(Sheet2).Cells(1, i).Value`

Comment: @Gman see Mathieu's answer.  we all missed it, but he got it.

Comment: @Gman not that I care much for the +15, but why put the checkmark on an answer that admits being incorrect?

Comment: @mathieuGuindon Please don't take this negatively but I think this was this answer that made me realize that my order of operations was incorrect. and was hopefully the root cause of my issue. I tried giving the check to both but it didn't work.